# causalml package: can the random forest handle continuous response variable?

Tags: python, random-forest, causalml

There is a [package](https://causalml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html) for Python called `causalml` which can be used for uplift modeling.
I'm trying to model the uplift when the response variable is continuous. The decision tree module in this package does not work on a continuous response variable, but it does when I use the random forest module.
I saw somewhere in the [documentation](https://github.com/uber/causalml/blob/master/examples/feature_interpretations_example.ipynb) that tree-based modules in this package are only designed for classification problems.
I was wondering if this package can handle continuous response variables at all. Can I trust the results I'm getting from the random forest module?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following [answer](https://github.com/uber/causalml/issues/143) uplift forest algorithms don't currently support continuous target variables.